# Замылить фоновую картинку средствами CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, эффекты

На Behance нашел интересный эффект.

> Могу ли я сделать такой фон средствами css?

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> -webkit-filter: blur

Отвечает за степень размытия.

```css
.background-image {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-position:center;
  
  display: block;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlpH8.jpg');
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;

  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="background-image"></div>
```

P.s картинку вставил вашу, для примера.